# Hyperlinks not working unless browser is already open

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I am using Internet Explorer 11 on a HP Ultrabook laptop (with multiple monitors) running Windows 8.1.

Whenever I click on a hyperlink in an email or reference document, it does not open an Internet Explorer session unless an IE window is already open and on top of the monitor screens.

Once I pull up the IE window and click the hyperlink again, it will open multiple windows to the same site, one for each time it was clicked. Can anyone explain this anomaly and offer a solution?

Comment: Idea: Is IE set as default browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the default programs for certain file types can get changed by a random program unknown to you.

Go to the start menu and type in Default Programs. Click set your default programs. Select Internet Explorer on the left and then click Set this program as default. See if the issue is resolved.

If that does not work, I would recommend downloading Chrome or Firefox and setting it as the default. Close all of your browsers and see if the link opens in Firefox/Chrome. If it does, open Internet Explorer again and set if to the default if it prompts you. If it does not, go to the settings menu in the top right (the gear icon) and select Internet Options. Go to the programs tab and click the Make default button. Uninstall Firefox/Chrome if you don't want them.

Good luck!